# How to run an executable file in python on Raspbian?

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Hello i'm been having some trouble with run a exe file on python. I'm using a Raspberry Pi and have not been able to find an answer that works. I've tried to use subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("/home/pi/Desktop/file.exe")
```

only to get [Errno 8] Exec format error. I get the same thing with subprocess.call.

I tried to use os

```
import os
os.system("/home/pi/Desktop/file.exe")
```

I get no errors there but nothing happens.

I know the exe file works when I click on it, I know that the file path is correct. Is there anyway I could run this exe with my python program.

Comment: How does the raspberry Pi able to open .exe files? does it open it with Wine or another emulator?

Comment: Does it work on your Raspberry Pi (perhaps, from GUI) or on some other computer?

Comment: did you realize that .exe file are windows executable and not valid on Linux?

Comment: What exe is that? Unless it's actually a managed-only .NET application there's no way it can run on Raspbian.

Comment: Okay so I just realized its not an exe. It is a desktop configuration file. I made an exe open with the desktop file. However when I try this with subprocess with the new extension I get exec format error. with os.system I don't see anything happening

Comment: Try to open your file through `xdg-open` (i.e. `xdg-open /home/pi/Desktop/file.exe`) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, `.exe` files are windows executables. They are not compiled for Linux (Raspian) at all. however you can find the extension of your file by opening a terminal window, navigate to the desktop with `cd ~/Desktop/` Then run `ls -la` to list the folder contents.

On the other hand, if you are meaning a Python file to run then it will have the extension `.py`. To run these open up your terminal and navigate to your Desktop again using `cd ~/Desktop/` and run it with `python file.py`